# Google Calendar Api Documentation better than the official V3

Tags: calendar

Please I want to create Event in Google Calendar API but the documentation official is BAD I cant use it .. And someone here who can help me please!! Sorry with my english but I speak spanish!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree...

This helps a bit: [Google Calendar Events](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events)

Answer (score 0):

What is "bad" about the documentation? (Don't just complain; provide actionable feedback.) In the v3 docs, check out the [reference section on creating events](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/insert). There is even [sample code](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/insert?hl=es#examples) in Java, Python, PHP, and Ruby to help get you started just below the reference. In addition, below the sample code is the APIs Explorer where you can [issue requests with appropriate payload to the API and see the HTTP response](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/insert?hl=es#try-it) to ensure you're calling the API correctly and receiving the data you requested. If there's any additional way for us to improve the docs, please let us know!

UPDATE (Sep 2015): I created a [blogpost and video](http://wescpy.blogspot.com/2015/09/creating-events-in-google-calendar.html) that walks through some pseudocode (well, it's Python) for creating events. There are examples in most other languages too.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the process you are using, there are few examples for using asp.net and the service account option. I successfully created events via service account with granting domain-wide access. With this you just need to create an app, then service account for the app and follow the domain wide delegation steps on the google documentation pages. This option is great if you have an app that needs to create events without having to authenticate the user.

For working code and more info you can see what I used at-
[Google API Calender v3 Event Insert via Service Account using Asp.Net MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27005568/google-api-calender-v3-event-insert-via-service-account-using-asp-net-mvc)